# How to call a class inside another class?

Tags: java, methods

I'm working on one of my first Java assignments and need help with calling another method which is inside a different class. The purpose behind this is that I have created a `PowerShower` class that has a `shower()`method. Then I have created a `GrownUp` class which consists of a person, this person needs to call the `shower()` method inside of the `PowerShower` class.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class GrownUp 
{

GrownUp(int age, String name)
{
    name = "Bill";
    age = 36;
}    

PowerShower haveShower = new PowerShower(1,1,1,1);

//call PowerShower.shower()?

}
```

How would I call the method and attach it to the person constructor which I have created? Sorry for the simplicity of the question, I'm still new to Java. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can't write logic outside of methods. The `PowerShower haveShower = ...` is actually declaring a *field*, not a *local variable*. You "call" statement is not in any method, and that's not allowed. Move it inside a method, e.g. the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call classes. Instead, you call methods on a class instance. You must first instantiate (create) an object with the `new` operator. Then you can call methods on that object. You can learn more about classes and objects in [the Oracle Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public class GrownUp 
{

GrownUp(int age, String name)
{
    name = "Bill";
    age = 36;
}    

PowerShower haveShower = new PowerShower(1,1,1,1);
haveShower.shower();

}
```

You can call any method  of a class if it's a public method. Just by using a instance/object of that class.

Comment: The issue was because I didn't create a method to store `haveShwer.shower()` in. One last question, how does this relate to the constructor I created calling the method?